# Listens to the file system

Tags: c#

i want to write application how handle with files and listen to directory root and add to my application only files who created in the lase 2 days.

1. `FileSystemWatcher` Class can listen only to one directory or can do it with all the sub directories under my root folder ?
2. what is the best option to find only files who created in the lase 2 days ? (FileInfo.CreationTime ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the second question, you can iterate through the files in the directory and check their creation dates.

```
foreach (FileInfo fi in directory.GetFiles())
{
    if (fi.CreationTime.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2)) 
    {
        //process file
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use LINQ

```
var recentFiles = directory.GetFiles().Where(x =>
                                x.CreationTime.Date <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(-2))
                                .Select(x => x.Name)
                                .ToList();
```

You'll want to benchmark performance differences, but for a small number of files, I doubt there'd be a significant difference.

Answer (score 2):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx):

> Use FileSystemWatcher to watch for changes in a specified directory. You can watch for changes in files and **subdirectories** of the specified directory.

So to answer your first question, yes it can do it with all subdirectories of your root folder.

Comment: Please note that `FileSystemWatcher` doesn't appear to work in Windows 8 as expected.